# Mongo - Return scalar when select result contains only one field

Tags: mongodb

For records like that:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60a50118a9aa9deb2cbbbd0b"
  },
  "userId": "id10",
  "crmId": "HG3F5BG89"
}
```

Selecting only one field returns result:

```
findOne({'userId': 'id10'}, {'crmId': 1, '_id': 0})  # {'crmId': 'HG3F5BG89'}
```

If there any way to return scalar so that result for the example above was just **'HG3F5BG89'**?

Comment: no it is not possible in mongodb query. you can do it in client side. it will result object refer [findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

Comment: Try `findOne({'userId': 'id10'}).crmId`